# I have a blinking cursor whereever I click on whatever website, any suggestions?

Tags: firefox

Unfortunately I cannot remember exactly when my problem started, but it must have been around the time FF8ß was installed on my system. Everytime I use FF now

Answer (score 1):

Hit F7 to turn off the Caret browsing mode. It's an accessibility feature.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Accessibility.browsewithcaret

---

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/887096